# Using AsyncTask in Activity fails

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I have an application in which I wanted to store a list of items and I figured a database would do. I found out about the new Room API and tried using it, though I'm having some trouble getting it working. I have a background service which is supposed to write entries to the database. I read that using the singleton pattern was recomended, but I can't seem to get it working. When I try to retrieve all entries in my MainActivity, the list I get back is always empty, indicating that I wasn't able to save them from the start.

*Singleton db class*

```
@Database(entities = {TemperatureReading.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class DatabaseSingleton extends RoomDatabase {

    private static DatabaseSingleton INSTANCE;

    public abstract TemperatureReadingDao temperatureReadingDao();

    public static DatabaseSingleton getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DatabaseSingleton.class, "fireTempDatabase")
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

*Entity*

```
@Entity
public class TemperatureReading {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dateTime")
    private long dateTime;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    private String readingLocation;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    private float value;

    public long getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(long dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getReadingLocation() {
        return readingLocation;
    }

    public void setReadingLocation(String readingLocation) {
        this.readingLocation = readingLocation;
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}
```

*EntityDAO*

```
@Dao
public interface TemperatureReadingDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM temperatureReading")
    List<TemperatureReading> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM temperatureReading ORDER BY uid desc limit 1")
    TemperatureReading getLatest();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(TemperatureReading... temperatureReading);

    @Update
    void update(TemperatureReading... temperatureReading);

    @Delete
    void delete(TemperatureReading temperatureReading);
}
```

*Background service which saves to db*

```
private void saveTempDatabase(float tmpMessageAsFloat, long tmpMessageDateTime) {
    Log.d(TAG, "saveTempDatabase");
    TemperatureReading tr = new TemperatureReading();
    tr.setDateTime(tmpMessageDateTime);
    tr.setReadingLocation("XXX"); //TODO
    tr.setValue(tmpMessageAsFloat);
    DatabaseSingleton.getAppDatabase(getApplicationContext()).temperatureReadingDao().insertAll(tr);
}
```

*MainActivity were db is read from, uses Async task so it doesn't block UI*
    private void updateTemperature() {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateTemperature");

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<TemperatureReading> tr = DatabaseSingleton.getAppDatabase(MainActivity.this).temperatureReadingDao().getAll(); //List is always empty, no matter how many times I have called the saveTempDatabase() method in the service class.
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer agentsCount) {

        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Maybe it has to do with the context somehow?

EDIT:

Just tried adding `.allowMainThreadQueries()` when building the database and now it works. So for some reason my Async task isn't working?

Comment: show ur database builder class please

Comment: I have? It's in the Singleton class?

Comment: sorry i had skipped it..

Comment: "When I try to retrieve all entries in my MainActivity, the list I get back is always empty, indicating that I wasn't able to save them from the start" -- look at the actual database. For example, you could copy it to your development machine using Device File Explorer in Android Studio, then examine it using a SQLite client. If you are correct, and the data is not there, use a debugger or `Log` statements to ensure that your service is running and that `saveTempDatabase()` is getting called.

Comment: I have verified that the service is running and getting called. But I just figured out that if I allow .allowMainThreadQueries() the service can update the database, so it swallows the exception otherwise. How can a background service operate on the main thread?.. I will try using a Async task on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your AsyncTask seems to be wrong. You should return the list you would like to handle in doInBackground and then expect it in onPostExecute. Why do you always return 0?